# Adding an element from a list to another list

Tags: python

I have a list containing ID's of students:

```
ID = [1,2,3]
```

and i have a table containing student names and their hobby:

```
student = [['Jack','Fishing'],['Alice','Reading'],['Mun','Football']]
```

I want to concatenate the ID to the first position of each sublist within the student list where i obtain:

```
[[1,'Jack','Fishing'],[2,'Alice','Reading'],[3,'Mun','Football']]
```

I tried:

```
for i in range(len(student)):
    student = ID[i] + student[i]
```

but I'm getting an error saying unsupported operand type.

Comment: `student = [ID[i]] + student[i]` should work.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` with list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
ID = [1,2,3]
l = [['Jack','Fishing'],['Alice','Reading'],['Mun','Football']]

newList = [[i[0]]+i[1] for i in zip(ID, l)]
print(newList)
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 'Jack', 'Fishing'], [2, 'Alice', 'Reading'], [3, 'Mun', 'Football']]
```

Comment: could you separate the print statement? I want to create a new list for the output. So printing the new list should be what i need

Comment: @clink; Sure. Updated snippet.

Answer (score 1):

@clink when you write `ID[i]`, it picks an element from the list `ID`. All the elements in the list `ID` are of type `int`. Also, all the elements in the `students` list are of type `list`. Hence when you use `+` operator between an `int` and `list` types you get the error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

What you need to do is to put the `int` into a new `list` to get the results you are seeking. Below is the modified code:

```
ID = [1,2,3]
student = [['Jack','Fishing'],['Alice','Reading'],['Mun','Football']]
for i in range(len(student)):
    student[i] = [ID[i]] + student[i]
```

**Output**

```
[[1, 'Jack', 'Fishing'], [2, 'Alice', 'Reading'], [3, 'Mun', 'Football']]
```

Pay attention to a single change: `ID[i]` was changed to `[ID[i]]`.

Answer (score 0):

@Clink- The element you get from `range(len(student))` is `int` type and trying merge with list. You should merge iterable types. That's why you are getting this error.

*TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'*

You can try solutions given by Rakesh or can follow below approach.

```
[std.insert(0, ID[idx]) for idx, std in enumerate(student)]
```

**Output**
[[1, 'Jack', 'Fishing'], [2, 'Alice', 'Reading'], [3, 'Mun', 'Football']]

Answer (score 0):

just a little change:

```
ID = [1,2,3]
student = [['Jack','Fishing'],['Alice','Reading'],['Mun','Football']]
for i in range(len(student)):
    student[i].insert(0,ID[i])
print(student)
```

output:

```
[[1, 'Jack', 'Fishing'], [2, 'Alice', 'Reading'], [3, 'Mun', 'Football']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need loop or anything just try:

```
ID = [1,2,3]
student = [['Jack','Fishing'],['Alice','Reading'],['Mun','Football']]

print(list(zip(ID,student)))
```

output:

```
[(1, ['Jack', 'Fishing']), (2, ['Alice', 'Reading']), (3, ['Mun', 'Football'])]
```

If you don't want nested list then:

```
print(list(map(lambda x:[x[0],*x[1]],zip(ID,student))))
```

output:

```
[[1, 'Jack', 'Fishing'], [2, 'Alice', 'Reading'], [3, 'Mun', 'Football']]
```